# Manage timezone in rails multi-step form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a multistep form that store data in a session table. Before storing the data I make up for the time difference by creating an @offset variable that carries the timezone agent.

```
  @offset = DateTime.now.in_time_zone(params[:event][:time_zone]).utc_offset / 3600
  params[:event][:google_address] = current_user.google_address if params[:event][:google_address].blank?
  params[:event][:start] = DateTime.strptime(params[:event][:start], "%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %P")  - @offset.hours
  params[:event][:end] = DateTime.strptime(params[:event][:end], "%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %P") - @offset.hours
  session[:event_params].deep_merge!(params[:event]) if params[:event]
```

This works well, but if the user returns to the previous steps (before saving the form), the form bring back the GMT time. I would like to re-display the time in the users time zone in the input field.

Does anybody knows the trick please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store `params[:event][:time_zone]` in user's session once you have the data

`session[:timezone] = params[:event][:time_zone]`

And in previous step you can access this and display form accordingly

`session[:timezone] # will nil or value`